# Number of subscribers to a pub/sub channel and timeout

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

Currently working on a multi process / multi host nodeJS app I'm facing a problem and I need your help.

My app consist on process and each of them can host several unique jobs. I have to know in real time if a job is currently running or not on my system.

Here is my current solution:

- Each job subscribes to a channel "job.JOB_UUID"
- If a process wants to know if a job is currently running I push to "job.JOB_UUID" and check the subscribers count. If it's 1 = ok this job is running, if 0 is not.

This solution works pretty well except when network issues occur. Its probably due to the fact that Redis pub/sub don't have timeouts:

```
Note that the timeout only applies to number clients and it **does not apply** to Pub/Sub clients, since a Pub/Sub connection is a push style connection so a client that is idle is the norm.
```

Redis seems keep ghost subscribers and when I publish to a channel it returns me 1 subscriber but it not realy exist.

Have you an idea to manage this case ?

ps: my previous solution was:

- each job set a key "job_UUID" in redis with TTL set to 5s.
- the TTL is updated each second by each job
- to check if a job exist, I just check if "job_UUID" key exist
  The problem is that it's not in real time.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee your jobs won't crash, you can always go with a variation of your original solution.

each job set a key "job_UUID" in redis with TTL set to N (a big enough number for the process to finish, it will act only as timeout)
the job finishes, catching any exceptions during the execution.
Once the job finishes, it removes the key from redis

In this scenario, you always have real time. While the process is running, the value will be there. Only if your job dies without deleting the value will you see an inconsistency. The TTL will automatically remove the value once the safeguard timeout passes.

If you need something more robust with real time, then you might be using the wrong tool for the job. For process coordination ZooKeeper is quite amazing. Not as generic as Redis, and certainly a bit more complex to setup due to the distributed nature of the problem, but very very good for process orchestration and real time failovers.